# Removing raster values using a threshold in QGIS and interpolating

Tags: qgis, raster, kriging

I have an imagery (plant cell density) comprising vine rows and grass inter-rows.I'm trying to permanently remove all the values of inter-row grass through setting up a threshold value. The vines mostly have higher values than grass.

After removing all the grass values, I want to interpolate a new map (krig) using only vine values.
Would someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the raster calculator (Raster >> Raster Calculator) type:

```
(vines_layer > grass_layer)*vines
```

This will filter those values where `vines_layer` is greater than `grass_layer`, keeping only those values of `vines_layer` and NULL values elsewhere, then you may perform your krigging

Comment: it would create a new layer

Comment: Hi Elio,   thanks for your answer. Could you please explain a bit the (vines_layer > grass_layer)*vines? I don't have two layers for them but only one layer one band, meaning vines and grasses are all in the same band just with different values.

Comment: oh, so you should then use a threshold, such as (vines_grass_layer > 0.5)*vines_grass_layer, adjusting the number, only values higher than the number would be kept